# Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so'

Tags: server, apt, apache2, php

A few days ago I did my regular update using `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`. Everything worked fine, but later I realized php was playing some tricks on my server.

I started getting the following error message

```
`Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so' - 
/usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

I also got an error message for XML but that was fixed after a few installs. For some reason the file for the library mentioned isn't there.

I am using php7 on an Ubuntu 14.04 server (up-to-date) and of course it sometimes installs php5.6 stuff.

I googled a little and found out that I should install the `php-xml` and the `php-xsl` libraries. I did that, i even installed it for php5.6, 7.0, 7.1 and 7.2, using:

`apt-get install php-xsl php5.6-xsl php7.0-xsl php7.1-xsl php7.2-xsl`

I did that, after which I used `sudo /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart` and `service apache2 restart` and I got no errors, but when I open my sites I still get the XSL error.

When I run my `phpinfo()` in the **Additional .ini files parsed** section I get this: `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-xsl.ini` which is an alias for `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xsl.ini` and inside that document I have this:

```
; configuration for php xml module
; priority=20
extension=xsl.so
```

The thing is that this error message sometimes appears on Ajax requests thus breaking their results and it's quite annoying. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix this for me was to remove completely all php versions using

```
sudo apt-get purge php
sudo apt-get purge php7.0
sudo apt-get purge php7.1
sudo apt-get purge php7.2
```

After which I had to install it again including all the extensions I was using.

After that I had to disable the currently enabled php5.6 using `sudo a2dismod php5` and after that enable php7 using `sudo a2enmod php7.0`.

After that I restarted my server using `sudo service apache2 restart` and gradually had to enable certain php modules that I needed.